# Invalid Signature, code object is not signed at all. iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, unity-game-engine

I am trying to integrate a Unity project into my Flutter project.
I use this package: https://github.com/juicycleff/flutter-unity-view-widget

However, I get this message after trying to upload my app to the App Store.

I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing is working so far.

Current workflow:

- Export the project to iOS. Without any signing from the Unity side at all.
- Sign the package from Xcode, and I give the package the same bundle identifier as my app (not sure if this is right or wrong)
- Upload

The issue I get after I try to upload:
[image]

Unity version: 2022.1.1f1
Xcode version: 13.4.1